# Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No injector factory bound for Class

Tags: java, android, android-studio

This is the error :

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No injector factory bound for Class<com.asit1.readyapp.resturants.S1_RestaurantsList>
        at dagger.android.DispatchingAndroidInjector.inject(DispatchingAndroidInjector.java:136)
        at dagger.android.AndroidInjection.inject(AndroidInjection.java:59)
        at com.asit1.readyapp.utils.base.BaseActivity.onCreate(BaseActivity.java:59)
        at com.asit1.readyapp.resturants.S1_RestaurantsList.onCreate(S1_RestaurantsList.java:59)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7802)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7791)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1299)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3245)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3409) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2016) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930) 
2021-08-31 13:48:31.248 1939-1939/? E/netmgr: Failed to open QEMU pipe 'qemud:network': Invalid argument
2021-08-31 13:48:32.435 2703-2703/? E/BeaconBle: Missing BluetoothAdapter
2021-08-31 13:48:32.539 2703-2703/? E/BeaconBle: Scan couldn't start for Places
2021-08-31 13:48:32.749 2096-3370/? E/InputDispatcher: Window handle Window{dc2c9b3 u0 Application Error: com.asit1.readyapp} has no registered input channel
2021-08-31 13:48:32.775 2096-3370/? E/InputDispatcher: Window handle Window{dc2c9b3 u0 Application Error: com.asit1.readyapp} has no registered input channel
2021-08-31 13:48:32.782 2096-3370/? E/InputDispatcher: Window handle Window{dc2c9b3 u0 Application Error: com.asit1.readyapp} has no registered input channel
2021-08-31 13:49:09.766 2096-2125/? E/AppIdleHistory: Error writing app idle file for user 0
2021-08-31 13:49:30.421 1944-1944/? E/wifi_forwarder: RemoteConnection failed to initialize: RemoteConnection failed to open pipe
2021-08-31 13:49:31.319 1939-1939/? E/netmgr: Failed to open QEMU pipe 'qemud:network': Invalid argument
2021-08-31 13:50:30.092 1944-1944/? E/wifi_forwarder: RemoteConnection failed to initialize: RemoteConnection failed to open pipe
2021-08-31 13:50:31.380 1939-1939/? E/netmgr: Failed to open QEMU pipe 'qemud:network': Invalid argument
2021-08-31 13:51:30.228 1944-1944/? E/wifi_forwarder: RemoteConnection failed to initialize: RemoteConnection failed to open pipe
2021-08-31 13:51:31.396 1939-1939/? E/netmgr: Failed to open QEMU pipe 'qemud:network': Invalid argument
2021-08-31 13:51:33.070 2096-2125/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
2021-08-31 13:51:34.402 2703-23956/? E/BluetoothAdapter: Bluetooth binder is null
2021-08-31 13:52:30.560 1944-1944/? E/wifi_forwarder: RemoteConnection failed to initialize: RemoteConnection failed to open pipe
2021-08-31 13:52:31.494 1939-1939/? E/netmgr: Failed to open QEMU pipe 'qemud:network': Invalid argument
2021-08-31 13:52:43.412 2703-23956/? E/BluetoothAdapter: Bluetooth binder is null
2021-08-31 13:52:52.763 2096-5612/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
2021-08-31 13:53:30.467 1944-1944/? E/wifi_forwarder: RemoteConnection failed to initialize: RemoteConnection failed to open pipe
2021-08-31 13:53:31.543 1939-1939/? E/netmgr: Failed to open QEMU pipe 'qemud:network': Invalid argument
2021-08-31 13:54:17.753 2703-20678/? E/WakeLock: GCM_HB_ALARM release without a matched acquire!
2021-08-31 13:54:30.541 1944-1944/? E/wifi_forwarder: RemoteConnection failed to initialize: RemoteConnection failed to open pipe
2021-08-31 13:54:31.549 1939-1939/? E/netmgr: Failed to open QEMU pipe 'qemud:network': Invalid argument
2021-08-31 13:55:30.557 1944-1944/? E/wifi_forwarder: RemoteConnection failed to initialize: RemoteConnection failed to open pipe
2021-08-31 13:55:31.564 1939-1939/? E/netmgr: Failed to open QEMU pipe 'qemud:network': Invalid argument
2021-08-31 13:55:43.348 2096-2125/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
2021-08-31 13:55:59.002 2096-2125/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
2021-08-31 13:56:18.995 2096-2125/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
2021-08-31 13:56:19.001 2096-2125/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
2021-08-31 13:56:30.617 1944-1944/? E/wifi_forwarder: RemoteConnection failed to initialize: RemoteConnection failed to open pipe
2021-08-31 13:56:31.622 1939-1939/? E/netmgr: Failed to open QEMU pipe 'qemud:network': Invalid argument
2021-08-31 13:57:08.132 2703-20678/? E/WakeLock: GCM_HB_ALARM release without a matched acquire!
2021-08-31 13:57:08.143 2096-2125/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
2021-08-31 13:57:08.148 2096-2125/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
```

[Error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WCxBN.png)

Comment: Can you please explain the scenario in detail?  For example what dependencies you used or what code you wrote that led to this error.

Comment: //dagger2
    implementation 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android-support:2.20' // if you use the support libraries
    annotationProcessor 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android-processor:2.20'
    annotationProcessor 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.20'

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try adding this annotation to your class `@ContributesAndroidInjector`

Next time provide more information about what went wrong; show how your classes look like, etc. Copy and pasting only the error code makes it hard to see what went wrong.

Comment: //retrofit2
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.4.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'
    implementation "com.jakewharton.retrofit:retrofit2-rxjava2-adapter:1.0.0"